# force a specific user to logout in codeigniter with destroying his session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to force a user to logout when I change it's status to 'inactive' using session in codeigniter.

I used the method below, but it destroyed my own session:

```
function deactivate($user_Id)
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata(array('user_Id' => $user_Id));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I happened to need this feature implemented and here is how I did it:

1. record user session id as last_active_session in db after login
2. find that session id and delete it from session table when this user is banned or anything.

You can also use this to prevent concurrent login such as the last successful login user bump the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sess_destroy()` method instead:

```
function deactivate() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```

Comment: why would your and the user's session be maintained on the same browser? you are not building an application with the sophistication of Gmail, are you? where you can add multiple accounts on the same computer. and even there all the sessions are logged out simultaneously. you need to plan things out before you start programming

Comment: Whaat if admin's a system and he wants do force logout for some user which is having trouble?